# How to convert data read from file form Windows-1250 to UTF-8 with SSIS

Tags: ssis

My SSIS code read file encoded as windows-1250 and put it do database. But I want to display it later in web application (UTF-8). How to transform it quickly?

I think that best option is SSIS conversion, but HOW?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inserting data into the database, use 'DT_WSTR' as data type instead of 'DT_STR' in the SSIS package where 'W' in 'DT_WSTR' stands for Unicode.
Use 'nvarchar' as data type instead of 'varchar' in the database. It'll store your data in Unicode Format.